# Sum of all probabilities is not 1 in homework

Tags: probability, self-study

Excerpt from "A first course in Probability, 8ed"

> A student is taking a one-hour-time-limit makeup examination. Suppose the probability that the student will finish the exam in less than $x$ hours is $x/2$, for all $0 ... x ... 1$. Then, given that the student is still working after .75 hour, what is the conditional probability that the full hour is used?

What I am concerning here is $\int_0^1\frac{x}{2}dx=\frac{1}{4}$, which is not $1$. Therefore, this is not a probability distribution function.

Am I correct? Thank you

Comment: No; the function $x/2$ is the *cumulative* distribution function, not the probability distribution function ("... probability that the student will finish the exam in less than $x$ hours...").

Comment: The exam time is an even mixture of a uniform random variable with support on [0, 1], and a point mass at $x=1$.

Comment: As a cumulative distribution function it means all students finish by 2 hours.

Comment: @user20637 - That's fine, it's possible for students not to finish the exam in the allotted time at all.  It happens in real life!

Comment: @jbowman please make an answer so that I can accept. Thank you

Comment: @MinhTriet - Thanks!  I've done so.

Answer (score 2):

The information provided by the statement "Suppose the probability that the student will finish the exam in less than $x$ hours is $x/2, ...$ refers to the *cumulative* distribution function of the amount of time required to finish the exam, not the probability distribution function.  With a one-hour time limit, $x$ cannot be greater than $1$, at which time we can see that only half the students have finished the exam at all.  This is OK!  Students sometimes don't!

We can model this by observing that if a student doesn't finish the exam in the full hour, they have still used the full hour.  Consequently, the cumulative distribution function has a jump at $x=1$:

$$P(x) = {x \over 2} + {1 \over 2}1(x = 1)$$

where $1(a)$ is the indicator function that that takes on the value $1$ if its argument $a$ evaluates to "true" and $0$ if it evaluates to "false".

The cumulative distribution of time-to-completion given that the student has worked for $3/4$ of an hour will be:

$$P(x|x \geq 0.75) = {P(x) - P(0.75) \over 1-P(0.75)} = {P(x) - P(0.75) \over 1-0.375} = \left({8 \over 5}\right)(P(x) - 0.375)$$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $x$, and remembering the discrete mass at $x=1$, gives us the probability function:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p(x|x\geq 0.75) &=& {4 \over 5},\; x < 1 \\
&=& \left({8 \over 5}\cdot{1\over 2}=0.8\right),\; x=1
\end{eqnarray}$$

and the answer is evidently $0.8$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: The function x/2 is not a probability density function, but a part of a cumulative distribution function. It's integral thus does not need to sum up to 1. (And a note, for density function the integral which should add up to 1 should be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, not from 0 to 1).

Comment: This does not answer the question; see my comment in response to the OP.

Comment: From the OP "the probability that the student will finish the exam in less than x hours is x/2" so the probability that student will finish the exam under 1 hour is 1/2 so there is 1/2 probability that the student will need more than 1 hour.

Comment: @user20637: It's not $1/2$ probability that they need more than 1 hour, because the support of x ends at (but including the point) $x=1$ (since the time limit for the exam is 1 hour). So actually the probability is $1/2$ that they need exactly the maximum of 1 hour, and $1/2$ that they will finish early. If they finish early, the time they need is uniformly distributed between $[0,1\rangle$. (See also Simon Boge Brant's comment.)

Comment: @RubenvanBergen - it's possible that the students need more than one hour, and therefore haven't completed the test within the one hour time limit, although in some sense of the word they are "finished" just because the test ended.

Comment: You are not correct about the integral of a density function needing to be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.  Think of a Beta distribution, which has range $(0,1)$; integrating from $0$ to $1$ is all that is required.

Comment: @jbowman That comment looks misleading to me, because it is universally correct that density functions have all of $\mathbb R$ for their domains and the integral of a valid density over $\mathbb R$ must be $1.$  The point is that for practical calculation, the integral may be restricted to the support of the distribution--but that does not make the first statements any less correct.

Comment: @whuber - From a useful notation point of view, I don't think all integrals involving density functions in practical work such as this question "should be" written from $-\infty$ to $\infty$; I find it quite helpful in an aid to memory way to have the support of the distribution clearly delineated by the range of integration - and, as you say, for practical calculation you get the right answer.    I think writing the integral from $0$ to $1$ instead of from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ with an indicator function tacked on the end in practical situations is just fine, and the note in the answer is...

Comment: wrong on the merits.

Comment: @jbowman In comparing the present post to the question, I see your point: the parenthetical remark at the end about the range of integration itself is somewhat misleading, although correct. If I may speculate about the author's intentions, I would suppose what they were trying to suggest is, if you bear in mind that *one must get a reasonable result when integrating a density over all of $\mathbb R,$* then it becomes obvious that the OP's approach is problematic, because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x/2)\mathrm{d}x$ does not exist and $\int_0^\infty\min(x/2,1)\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.

Comment: @whuber - that's a good point, and one that should probably have been introduced into any class with the label "Probability" associated with it at an early stage.  I can see in retrospect that my initial comment did not make the distinction between "useful in applied work" and "mathematically correct" in its outlook and therefore, as you noted, not actually correct.